# Microsoft Graph Create Contact Issue

Tags: php, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

When I create a contact in microsoft graph I'm getting the following issue

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: xxx
client-request-id: xxx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 13:23:55 GMT
Content-Length: 315

{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
    "message": "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxx",
      "date": "2020-05-29T13:23:55"
    }
  }
}
```

This is happening with the following postdata

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx/contacts HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
SdkVersion: Graph-php-1.12.0
Authorization: xxxx
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.3 curl/7.51.0 PHP/5.6.31
Content-Length: 209

{"title":"Mr.","givenName":"Eric","surname":"Klinitski","businessPhones":"30 1235436","mobilePhone":"00 49 1234 6543125","emailAddresses":[{"address":"erick@xxx.com","name":"erick@xxx.com"}]}
```

I'm using the PHP SDK I've managed produce get requests already

Comment: I think `businessPhones` should be a list of objects, not a number.

Comment: Yes, it should be a list. Check the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request